# SQL - How do I simplify this easy query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, refactoring

I am using SQL Server 2005.

How could I refactor this query?

```
SELECT Total, Installs, Service, tot.ls_chg_dte_ojb
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) [Total], ls_chg_dte_ojb
         FROM [COMPL_INST_SVC]
         GROUP BY ls_chg_dte_ojb) tot

  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) [Service], ls_chg_dte_ojb
         FROM [COMPL_INST_SVC]
         WHERE job_class_ojb = 'S' 
         GROUP BY ls_chg_dte_ojb) svc on svc.ls_chg_dte_ojb = tot.ls_chg_dte_ojb

  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) [Installs], ls_chg_dte_ojb
         FROM [COMPL_INST_SVC]
         WHERE job_class_ojb in ('C', 'R') 
         GROUP BY ls_chg_dte_ojb) ins on ins.ls_chg_dte_ojb = tot.ls_chg_dte_ojb
```

Comment: Is that even correct? Why does the total only include the values where job_class_obj = 'S'?

Comment: What's the supposed difference between the first inner select ('total') and the second ('service')?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment below, you should not use single quotes for delimiting aliases - this syntax is being deprecated. Use [square brackets], "double quotes" or no delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Total and Service counts are counting the same exact thing, so you'll need to fix that, but here's basically how you do the counts in a simpler way:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN job_class_ojb = 'S' THEN 1 END) AS [Total],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN job_class_ojb = 'S' THEN 1 END) AS [Service],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN job_class_ojb in ('C', 'R') THEN 1 END) AS [Installs]
FROM
  [COMPL_INST_SVC]
```

Comment: I think you meant `SUM` not `COUNT` - `COUNT` in this case will return the same value in each column, since `COUNT` just counts the row, not the actual values. Also you should not use single quotes for delimiting aliases - this syntax is being deprecated. Use [square brackets], "double quotes" or no delimiters.

Comment: `SUM` can return `NULL` in some cases, which can be a problem. Better to use `COUNT` for that reason.

Comment: Single quotes are indeed deprecated. I ought to update my answer.

Comment: `SUM` returns `NULL` if there are no matching rows. `COUNT` returns the right answer; it counts only when its argument is non-NULL. Side-note: I prefer to use `1` in the expression, but any non-NULL argument would suffice.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, not sure why I always stay away from `COUNT` in these cases or what kind of brain fart I am having tonight but I suspect it's time to step away from the computer.

Comment: I like this the answer because of COUNT instead of SUM you gave forgot to group by [ls_chg_dte_ojb]

Answer (score 2):

Two of your sub-selects are the same. Ignoring the 'Service' one, try something along the lines of

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN job_class_ojb = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Total,
SUM(CASE WHEN job_class_ojb = 'C' or
              job_class_ojb = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Installs
FROM COMPL_INST_SVC
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the Totals subquery should not include the `WHERE job_class_ojb = 'S'` condition - if so, I suggest:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN job_class_ojb = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Service,
       SUM(CASE WHEN job_class_ojb in ('C','R') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Installs,
       ls_chg_dte_ojb
FROM COMPL_INST_SVC
GROUP BY ls_chg_dte_ojb
```

Comment: Your answer is the only one which included the 'GROUP BY' however I preferred using 'COUNT'